# Python exe too slow

Tags: python, performance, exe

I made a python program that read data from csv, sort it and show graphs using Plotly. When I tested using the .py file it works really fast, then when I convert it to .exe it starts to became slower. Here is my code

```
print("Importando modulos")
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import time
import gc
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import plotly.express as px
print("Modulos Importados")
try:
    start_time = time.time()
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("E3_converter.py"))
    def grafic_interface(dicc):
        def show(event):
            df=dicc[event.widget['text']]
            fig = px.line(df, x='Time', y=['B003.AQ',"B004.AQ"])
            fig.show()
        form=Tk()
        form.title("Analisis de Sistema Monitoreado")
        form.iconbitmap("D:\Escritorio\pruebas\e3solutionsfinalsolo.ico")
        form['background']="#1500b0"
        nombre = Label(text='FECHAS\n', fg = '#ffffff',bg = '#1500b0', font = 'Helvetica 16 bold')
        nombre.grid(row=1, column=2)
        nombre.place(x=150,y=10)
        cont=2
        i=0
        for date in dicc:
            if cont%2==0:
                data=Button(form,text=str(date))
                data.place(x=50,y=70+(30*i))           
                data.bind("<Button-1>", show)
            else:
                data=Button(form,text=str(date))
                data.place(x=250,y=70+(30*i)) 
                i+=1.2
                data.bind("<Button-1>", show)
            cont+=1
        y=(int(cont)/2)*60
        form.geometry("400x"+str(int(y)))
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time)) 
        form.mainloop()

    LIST_CSV=[]
    files=list(glob.glob(path+"\\*.csv"))
    if len(files)>0:
        df_one=pd.read_csv(files[0])
        LIST_CSV.append(df_one)
        print("Recolectando datos")
        for i in range(1,len(files)):
            df_temp=pd.read_csv(files[i])
            LIST_CSV.append(df_temp)
        print("Uniendo datos")
        df=pd.concat(LIST_CSV)
        df['Time']= pd.to_datetime(df['Time']) 
        print("Ordenando datos")
        df.sort_values(by='Time')
        global_dates=list(df.Time.dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y').unique())
        while (global_dates.count(np.nan)): 
            global_dates.remove(np.nan)
        global_dates.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%m-%Y"))
        GLOBAL_DICT={} 
        for date in global_dates:
            print("Realizando query fecha:   "+str(date))
            datetime_object = datetime.strptime(str(date), '%d-%m-%Y')
            data=df.loc[(df["Time"].dt.month==datetime_object.month) & (df["Time"].dt.day==datetime_object.day)]
            GLOBAL_DICT[str(date)]=data
        grafic_interface(GLOBAL_DICT)          
    else:
        print("No existe ningun archivo de extension csv en este folder")
except:
    time.sleep(40)
```

I added a print to see when it starts execute.
My output looks like this
[image]

It takes around 10 minutes!!! to show me the first print

Comment: what did you used to convert it  into exe and how?

Comment: He probably used PyInstaller.

Comment: yes I used PyInstaller and I used auto-py-to-exe to do it easily

Comment: and what do you mean with becoming slower?

Comment: Does the `print` include a `flush=True` argument? Without it, the buffer can take quite some time to fill, so you might not see any output for a while. I'd also add logging to your bare `except:` (and not use a completely bare `except:`) as you may be getting exceptions you don't expect, and sleeping 40 seconds every time it happens.

Comment: When I say slower I mean that its taking forever to show me the first print, that is even before importing modules

Comment: You are running multiple files command or single file command  ?